# Calculator in division operation using C

Tags: c, calculator

I am making a calculator using C language. But the problem is that I am stuck in division.
I want that when I input 0 divided by 0, it will  print undefined and if a number divided by zero will print cannot be divide by zero (which seems I got this).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){

    float num1, num2, total;
    int a;
    char choice;
    clrscr();
    printf("What operation you want to perform?\n 1. Addition\n 2. Subtraction\n 3. Multiplication\n 4. Division\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    switch(a)  {
        case 1:  //Addition
            printf("Addition\n Enter two numbers to be added\n");
            scanf("%f%f",&num1, &num2);
            total=num1 + num2;
            printf("\nThe total is: %f + %f = %f\n", num1, num2, total);
            printf("\nDo want to continue? Y or N:  ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                main();
            else
                exit(1);
            break;
        case 2: //Subtraction
            printf("Subtraction\n Enter two numbers to be subtract\n");
            scanf("%f%f", &num1, &num2);
            total=num1 - num2;
            printf("\nThe Difference is: %f + %f = %f\n", num1, num2, total);
            printf("\nDo you want to continue? Y or N:  ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                main();
            else
                exit(1);
            break;
        case 3: //Multiplication
            printf("Multiplication\n Enter two numbers to be multiplied\n");
            scanf("%f%f",num1, num2);
            total=num1*num2;
            printf("\nThe product is: %f * %f = %f\n", num1, num2, total);
            printf("\nDo you wish to continue? Y or N:  ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                main();
            else
                exit(1);
            break;

        case 4: //Division
            abcd:
            printf("Division\n Enter two numbers to be divide\n");
            scanf("%f%f",&num1, &num2);
                if(num2==0.0)
                      {    printf("\n %f cannot be divided by zero\n\n", num1);    // ;(
                     goto abcd;}
                else if(num1==0.0 && num2==0.0)                    //This is my problem here.
                    {printf("\nIts Undefined. 0 / 0\n\n ");
                    }
            total=num1/num2;
            printf("\nThe qoutient is %f / %f = %f\n", num1, num2, total);
            printf("\nDo you want more? Y or N:  ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                main();
            else
                exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Can you add letters? LOL only numbers");
            printf("\nDo you want to continue? Y/N ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                main();
            else
                exit(1);
            break;
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: wholly frap! What happened to all the formatting

Comment: Somebody keeps messing it up, and I keep fixing it.

Comment: Seems like I was editing the question the same time you were editing the question :-P @ErnestFriedman-Hill - or it could be a bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
if(num2==0.0)
    // division by zero
else if(num1==0.0 && num2==0.0)
    // zero/zero is undefined
```

The problem is that if both numbers are 0.0, it's caught by the first test, and the second is never executed.

You need to test for both numbers being zero *first*, and then check whether the second number is zero.

Or you can combine the two tests:

```
if (num2 == 0.0) {
    if (num1 == 0.0) {
        // zero / zero
    }
    else {
        // non-zero / zero
    }
}
else {
    // ok
}
```

Comment: Wow ! i can't believe i can get answer here fast. You give me the idea. Here is my answer: if(num1==0.0 && num2==0.0){printf("\nUndefined");goto abcd;} else if(num2==0.0){printf("\Cannot divide by zero");goto abcd;

Answer (score 1):

Your `if else` statements are not ordered correctly.
Always try to put the case that is most specific before the more general cases.

So in your case, the specific case is when `num1 == 0.0 && num2 == 0.0`

Whereas the general case is `num2 == 0.0`

Also, your program would crash when both `num1` and `num2` are zero, seeing as it divides them anyway in that case.

Comment: tnx sir ! something i learned today :)